# How do I get a list of all of the members in a discord server using discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to generate a list of all of the members in my server:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            print(member)
```

However it is only printing itself and none of the other members. Have I written something wrong or is there something I need to do with the bot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable `intents.members`

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)
# Or if you're using `discord.Client`
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Also make sure to enable them in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

[docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?)